# Extracting a substring until and including a matching word using bash tools

Tags: bash

I have file names like these:

```
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
func/sub-01_task-pfobloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
func/sub-01_task-rest_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
```

and from each file name I want to extract the part until and including the word `bold` so that in the end I have:

```
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold
func/sub-01_task-pfobloc_run-01_bold
func/sub-01_task-rest_run-01_bold
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail? Did you read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html ? Try `${F%_space*}`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is to just remove `bold` and everything after, then replace `bold`. Obviously, this only works if the terminating string is fixed, as in this case.

```
$ f=func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
$ echo "${f%%bold*}"
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_
$ echo "${f%%bold*}bold"
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you want?

```
echo func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz | sed -e 's#bold_.*$#bold#'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes definitely! could you explain what this syntax mean: 's#bold_.*$#bold#' ?

Comment: Sure.  s means sed is going to do a substitution (i.e. find and replace).  The hash (#) is the delimiter between the find string and the replace string.  The "bold_.*$" is the find string.  It is going to search for "bold_" followed by zero or more of any character (.*) until the end of the string ($).  Everything found in the find string is to be replaced with "bold".  The find string is following normal regular expression pattern matching.  You can find out more about regular expressions on any number of websites.

Answer (score 0):

This is (needlessly) clever: remove the *prefix* ending with "bold"
 and then so some substring index arithmetic based on the length of the suffix that's left over:

```
$ file=func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
$ tmp=${file#*bold}
$ keep=${file:0:${#file}-${#tmp}}
$ echo "$keep"
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold
```

If $file does not contain "bold", then $keep will be empty: we can give it the value of $file if it is empty:

```
$ file=foobar
$ tmp=${file#*bold}
$ keep=${file:0:${#file}-${#tmp}}
$ : ${keep:=$file}
$ echo "$keep"
foobar
```

---

But seriously, do [what chepner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763021/7552).

Answer (score 0):

using Perl

```
> echo "func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz" | perl -e 'while (<>) { $_=~s/(.*bold)(.*)/\1/g; print } '
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to glenn's solution, but a bit "less clever" in that it doesn't use substrings, just nested substitutions:

```
$ while IFS= read -r fname; do echo "${fname%"${fname#*bold}"}"; done < infile
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold
func/sub-01_task-pfobloc_run-01_bold
func/sub-01_task-rest_run-01_bold
```

The substitution `"${fname%"${fname#*bold}"}"` says:

- Remove `"${fname#*bold}"` from the end of each filename, where
- `"${fname#*bold}"` is everything up to and including `bold` removed from the front of the filename

Example for the first filename with explicit intermediate steps:

```
$ fname=func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
$ echo "${fname#*bold}"
_space-T1w_preproc.nii.gz
$ echo "${fname%"${fname#*bold}"}"
func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=func/sub-01_task-biommtloc_run-01_bold_space-T1w_preproc.nii.g
echo "${f//bold*/bold}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using `sed` for this task. First take all of your input filenames and stick them in a file, call it `namelist.txt` in the current directory. The following will work, as long as your `sed` supports extended regular expressions (which most will, particularly GNU sed). Note that the flag for extended regular expressions may differ a bit between platforms, check your `sed` manual page. On my Linux, it is `-r`.

```
bash -c "sed -r 's/(sub-01_task-.{1,10}_run-01_bold).+/\\1/' namelist.txt"
```